# ActionForm pattern in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, migration, struts-1, model-driven, actionform

I am migrating a Struts 1 application to Struts 2. In the Struts 2 documentation which it compares the difference it says,

> Struts 2 also supports the `ActionForm` pattern, as well as POJO form
> objects and POJO Actions.

But i dont find any classes similar to `ActionForm` or `ValidatorForm` in Struts 1. So in this case how can I keep the existing `ActionForm` pattern in Struts 1 with the new Struts 2 jars?

Comment: `ModelDriven` would be the more-or-less equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to read further

> Rich object types, including business or domain objects, can be used
> as input/output objects. The `ModelDriven` feature simplifies taglib
> references to POJO input objects.

To keep existing `ActionForm` pattern see the [Struts 1 Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/struts-1/).